# MUI DataGrid. Cell format after editing

Tags: material-ui

After editing cell i the get row in onRowEditStop event. And the value I edited is string. How can I make it number? valueFormatter didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use `valueParser` to convert the value from string to  number. From the [docs](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#value-parser-and-value-setter):

> You can use the valueParser property in the column definition to modify the value entered by the user—for example, to convert the value to a different format

Comment: Thx. I finished up with type: 'number' property of column

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I recently used that will format the DataGrid numbers with commas and

{ field: 'Balance', headerName: 'Balance', width: 200, **type: 'number'},**

This formatted the number with commas as follows:  31,584,123